# Need to add numbers that are printed from loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm just practicing with loops and arrays and I am a little stuck on something. So essentially I have an array and I am trying to add all the positive numbers in the array and subtract this from all the negatives.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int temp;
int array[4];

array[0] = 2;
array[1] = 5;
array[2] = 8;
array[3] = 6;

if (array[0] > 0) {

    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (array[i]%2 == 0){
            cout <<array[i] << endl;
        }           
    }
}

else { return 0; }
}
```

So it gets that 2, 6 and 8 are the positive numbers but how can I make the loop then add these numbers, once I get this bit I can probably figure out how to subtract the negative numbers from this.

Cheers.

Hopefully everything is pretty clear.

Comment: you want a sum of all the positive numbers in the array?

Comment: Make it even simpler first: write a loop that sums *all* the elements and then print the result. (You're testing whether the number is even, not positive, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

I will just store them in a local variable.

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (array[i]%2 == 0){
            cout << array[i] << endl;
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Yes you're testing for Even and odd numbers, so:

```js
    int Main(){
      
      //initialize your array
    int sumEven = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (array[i]%2 == 0){
        sumEven += srray[i];
      }else{
        sumOdd += array[i];
}
    }
      return sumOdd - sumEven;
    }
```

Comment: It is not really clear that the OP wants to print even and odd numbers. That's what he's doing with that modulo 2, sure, but in the question he talks about positive and negative numbers. And you have posted a Javascript snippet; this question is tagged as C++. I was going to [edit] the question and fix it for you, but even the braces are wrong (one is not closed). This requires some more work. Please check what you can improve. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks@Fabio I have added the missing brace. @Bose is it even and odd or positive and negative numbers you want to test for?